# Sort a Range column based on the sequence of column values from another Range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

I have a Range in a worksheet as shown below that I want to custom sort on `Beta` column from another worksheet range column `Status`:

```
+---------+----------+-----+
| Alpha   | Beta     | Gama|
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 1  | COMPLETE | 245 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 2  | PENDING  | 344 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 3  | COMPLETE | 122 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 4  | COMPLETE | 111 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 5  | PENDING  | 101 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 6  | PENDING  | 222 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 7  | PROGRESS | 343 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 8  | PROGRESS | 256 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 9  | PROGRESS | 606 |
+---------+----------+-----+
| PROJ 10 | COMPLETE | 234 |
+---------+----------+-----+
```

like this:

```
+---------+----------+---------+
| Alpha   | Beta     | Gama    |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 7  | PROGRESS | 343     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 8  | PROGRESS | 256     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 9  | PROGRESS | 606     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 2  | PENDING  | 344     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 5  | PENDING  | 101     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 6  | PENDING  | 222     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 1  | COMPLETE | 245     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 3  | COMPLETE | 122     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 4  | COMPLETE | 111     |
+---------+----------+---------+
| PROJ 10 | COMPLETE | 234     |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

based on unique values from another Range column:

```
+----------+
| STATUS   |
+----------+
| PROGRESS |
+----------+
| PENDING  |
+----------+
| COMPLETE |
+----------+
```

Is this possible using a custom sort function in VBA? e.g. something like below (not working):

```
Sub SortTable()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With ws1
  Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(11, 3))
End With

With ws2
  Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(4, 3))
End With
  
With rng1.Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=rng2.ListColumns("Status").Range, Order:=xlAscending
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "unique values from another Range column" mean? Are there in the range exactly as you show us, or there are many occurrences and the code should extract the unique ones? Then, will `rng2` be the sorting criteria range, in your code?

Comment: `Rng2` is a unique values range list that has matching values in `Beta` column of `Rng1`. Using that order (sequence), the `Rng1` columns (`Beta`) need to be sorted.

Comment: In PROJ 3 and PROJ 10, the priority is PROJ 10. This is a character, so 10 is faster than 3. It will be necessary to change the format of the data. Comparing 3 and 10, 10 is faster. Comparing 03 and 10, 03 is the fastest ranking.

Comment: sorry i did not understand. The idea is just to sort on the `Beta` column values as per the order given in `Rng2`.

Comment: If the Alpha field is 3, 10 is a number, the priority is 3
It is fast, but there is a number after it mixed with the letter, so you have to look at it as a letter as a whole. In this case, 3 is placed behind 10 in sort order. This means that you must change the number format to 03,10 or, if the unit is larger, to 003, 010 to ensure proper alignment.

Comment: @Dy.Lee what is the code that you have in mind? maybe sharing the same would make more sense. BTW the Alpha column is a text field.

Comment: There is no standard method to sort in this way. But, using a Dictionary and matching its keys with the criteria range/array, it can be done, I think... I will try posting such a code.

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It assumes that the **criteria range is in "A1:A4" of the "Sheet2" worksheet**. The code will drop the processed result starting from "E2". If you like its return, please adapt the last code line in `ws1.Range("A2")`. It will overwrite the existing data:

```
Sub SortTable()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 Dim Dim rngC As Range, arrL, arr, arrFin, mtch, dict As Object, arrL, arr, arrFin, mtch, dict As Object

 Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

 With ws1
    arrL = .Range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(11, 3)).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 End With

 With ws2
     Set rngC = .Range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(4, 1))
 End With

 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrL), 1 To UBound(arrL, 2)) 'redim the final array
 Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrL) 'create unique keys in the dictionary and add the necessary information separated by "|" and "::"
     dict(arrL(i, 2)) = dict(arrL(i, 2)) & "|" & arrL(i, 1) & "::" & arrL(i, 3)
 Next i

 For i = 1 To rngC.rows.count
    mtch = Application.match(rngC(i, 1).value, dict.Keys, 0)
    arrL = Split(Mid(dict.items()(mtch - 1), 2), "|")
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrL)
        arr = Split(arrL(j), "::")
        k = k + 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = arr(0): arrFin(k, 2) = dict.Keys()(mtch - 1): arrFin(k, 3) = arr(1)
    Next
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content at once:
 ws1.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

**Edited to prove no Match limitation for > 5000 rows**:

Please, copy and run the next code:

```
Sub testMatchLimitations()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, mtch, arr
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 sh.Range("C1:C2").value = Application.Transpose(Array("AAA1", "AAA2"))
 
 sh.Range("C1:C2").AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range("C1:C" & sh.rows.count), Type:=xlFillDefault
 arr = sh.Range("C1:C" & sh.rows.count).value
 mtch = Application.match("AAA1048566", arr, 0)
  Debug.Print mtch
End Sub
```

It will raise **no error for the maximum Excel number of rows**...

**Second edit**:

A second (simpler) version, adding a helper column and sort according to it:

```
Sub SortTable_1()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long
 Dim rngC As Range, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, arrL, arrFin, mtch

 Set ws1 = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set ws2 = ws1.Next ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 lastR = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastCol = 4 'it can be calculated...
 With ws1
    arrL = .Range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(lastR, 3)).value
 End With

 With ws2
    Set rngC = .Range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(4, 1))
 End With
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrL), 1 To 1)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrL)
    mtch = Application.match(arrL(i, 2), rngC, 0)
    If Not IsError(mtch) Then
        arrFin(i, 1) = mtch
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no match in the criteria range for value in C" & i + 1 & "(" & arrL(i, 2) & "...": Exit Sub
    End If
 Next i
 
 ws1.cells(1, lastCol).value = "Rank"
 ws1.cells(2, lastCol).Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = arrFin
 ws1.Range("A1", ws1.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Sort key1:=ws1.Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
 ws1.cells(1, lastCol).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: i think there is an easier way than resorting to Dictionaries and Arrays. The code though large, is good for (i think <=5k) data but will fail on this line `mtch=Application.match(arrC(i), dict.Keys, 0)` for anything larger.

Comment: @sifar **Why should it fail**? This can happen only if there are differences between the Criteria range elements and the strings used in  "Beta" column. Or you wrongly declared `mtch`. Maybe some extra spaces there... If this would be the case, the code can be adapted to trim the used elements. Did that happen in your workbook? If so, if not something confidential, can you share it? Even with dummy data... And which to be that "easier way"? I have in mind something different, but I am curious about what you have in mind... :) I only played with VBA.

Comment: I am not saying it won't work. But through experience I have found it unreliable for larger data...Even VBA.Filter or Application.Index etc.

Comment: @sifar Did you try the above code? If so, and it stops on error at that line, moving the cursor over `arrC(i)`, what does it show? You did not say anything about the workbook sharing...

Comment: I cannot share as i am writing code directly into a sharepoint workbook on an enterprise account. I will certainly try it once i create a dummy file populated with a larger dataset (even you can try and share one).

Comment: @sifar I think it is good for you to understand that `match` method is done for a small array/(range, if necessary). The dictionary keys, if no misspelled words used as criteria, **should have only three keys**, or a few others if any ! Why do you suspect that it will fail on that line?

Comment: Hi, you are not getting the point. My data is very large and a single `ArrC(i)` list of values could exceed 5k. The issue lies with `Application.Match` that won't be able to handle large arrays. Can your code handle ~1 mil rows data with each unique values >5k? Would you be able to try it and share your results in a workbook?

Comment: @sifar Do you understand that `ArrC(i)` is the **criteria array**? Should I understand that **are there 1 mill Beta criteria**? I tried choosing this approach to avoid matching in a big range/array. I have in mind a different (simpler) way, but I will like to clarify this issue before posting it... :)

Comment: @sifar I edited the above answer and placed a test procedure to prove that `Match` does not have any limitations related to the range number of rows. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @sifar I will leave my office in some minutes and have something to finish. So, I edited the answer again and placed another simpler code which use a helper column and sort according to its values. I do not know which of them will be faster, but I think that both of them should work. This second one, will send a message if no match between the unique criteria and the processed data range exists. The code will stop and you need to correct the criteria range. Of course, if the case...

Comment: @sifar You did not say anything in your question about the range to be processed size. I analyzed my previous code and I deduced that the single line which may be problematic was the one using `Transpose`, which have some limitations in terms of number of rows. So I adapted the code to use a range instead of the array. `Match` in a range is a little faster than in an array, but not significantly. You may test that in the code i posted to prove that its limitations against the processed number of rows is a myth... Now, i am leaving my office. I will be able to react only when I will be at home.

Answer (score 2):

How to use sql. The result is in a new sheet Sheet3.

```
Sub DoSQL(Ws As Worksheet, strSQL As String)
 
    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer
 
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
 
 
    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn
 
    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
Sub test()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vS
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set Ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Ws1
        vDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vS = Split(vDB(i, 1))
        vDB(i, 1) = vS(0) & " " & Format(Val(vS(1)), "000#")
    Next i
    With Ws1
        .Range("d1") = "Alpha2"
        .Range("d2").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    End With
    
    Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    strSQL = "select a.Alpha, Beta, Gama "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM "
    strSQL = strSQL & "( select * from [Sheet1$]  , [Sheet2$] as b "
    strSQL = strSQL & "where beta = b.status ) as a "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY b.status desc, a.Alpha2 "

    DoSQL Ws, strSQL
End Sub
```

### Sheet1 image

Create a new field Alpah2.

[image]

### Sheet3 image

[image]

Comment: i tried using ADO earlier, but found that it does not work properly with Excel 365 if the workbook is stored on cloud for e.g. Onedrive or Sharepoint. The line where it would cause a problem is `ThisWorkbook.FullName` where it may give an `https://` address that ADO cannot translate. So had to resort to backward compatible code.

Comment: @sifar, Sorry, I also don't know this part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract of a simpler solution that i derived using [CustomLists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.addcustomlist).

```
Sub SortRange()
.....

'Custom Sort `Rng1`
xLastColumn = .Range("1:1").Cells(.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
xLastRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

KeyValues = wk3.Cells.Range("F46:F54").Value2 ' `Rng2
n = Application.GetCustomListNum(KeyValues)
Application.DeleteCustomList n
            
Application.AddCustomList listArray:=KeyValues
sortNumber = Application.CustomListCount
            
wk2.Sort.SortFields.Clear
            
wk2.Sort.SortFields.Add _
  Key:=wk2.Range(yCell.Offset(1, 0), wk2.Cells(xLastRow, yCell.Column)), _
  SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
  Order:=xlAscending, _
  CustomOrder:=sortNumber, _
  DataOption:=xlSortNormal
          
  With wk2.Sort
    .SetRange wk2.Range(wk2.Cells(1, 1), wk2.Cells(xLastRow, xLastColumn))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
  End With
End With

.....

End Sub
```